# Setting multiple states in custom hook

Tags: reactjs, web, axios, react-hooks, pagination

I'm tyring to make a React custom hook where it recieves a url as a parameter to retrieve data using axios. I can retrieve the data I need with this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

//Takes a url parameter
const useList = (url) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState( [] );
    
    //Gets data from url parameter passed in and sets the data in State.
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(data => {
            setData(data.data.content);
            console.log(data);
            
        })
    }, [url]);

    return {data};
}

export default useList;
```

I'd like to add another state:

```
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
```

and then have that state updated within the same useEffect hook, since the response I retrieve from the URL has pagination data showing totalPages.

I added it to the useEffect hook like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(data => {
            setData(data.data.content);
            setPageNumber(pageNumber.data.totalPages);
        })
    }, [url]);
```

And get the error:
[image]

How can I update multiple states within one useEffect hook? (Pretty new to React)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pageNumber is initialized with a number so you cant do pageNumber.data, you should do the following:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then(data => {
            setData(data.data.content);
            setPageNumber(data.totalPages);
        })
    }, [url]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Depending on the api design its setPageNumber(data.totalPages) or setPageNumber(data.data.totalPages)